# How to get all the members in an array in azure cosmosdb sql query?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following json in my container on azure cosmosdb:

```
    {
        "Data": {
            "High school": [
                {
                    "ClassData": [
                        {
                            "Teacher": "Hess Lyons",
                            "NumberOfStudents": "21",
                            "AverageScore": "82.9"
                        },
                        {
                            "Teacher": "Kristine Melendez",
                            "NumberOfStudents": "21",
                            "AverageScore": "91.0"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ClassData": [
                        {
                            "Teacher": "Lottie Poole",
                            "NumberOfStudents": "17",
                            "AverageScore": "88.6"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I would like to get all the pairs of 'NumberOfStudents' and  'AverageScore', where the 'NumberOfStudents' is 21.
For example:

```
[
{
    "NumberOfStudents": "21",
    "AverageScore": "82.9"
},
{
    "NumberOfStudents": "21",
    "AverageScore": "91.0"
}
]
```

I just don't understand how to get all the members in the array.
All I have for now is those queries:

```
1.select c.AllData.HighSchool[0].ClassData[0].NumberOfStudents,
         c.AllData.HighSchool[0].ClassData[0].AverageScore
    FROM c 
    where c.AllData.HighSchool[0].ClassData[0].NumberOfStudents = '21'

2.select results.NumOfStdnts_AvgScore[0].NumberOfStudents,
        results.NumOfStdnts_AvgScore[0].AverageScore from 
       (SELECT ARRAY(select classData.NumberOfStudents,
                    classData.AverageScore
                    from classData in highSchool.ClassData) as NumOfStdnts_AvgScore
     FROM highSchool in items.AllData.HighSchool) as results
where results.NumOfStdnts_AvgScore[0].NumberOfStudents = '21'
```

But these queries only return the first member in each array.
I would really appreciate any help, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get this right using:

```
select
    p.NumberOfStudents,
    p.AverageScore
 FROM f
    JOIN c IN f.AllData.HighSchool
    JOIN p IN c.ClassData
where p.NumberOfStudents = '21'
```

Comment: Where's `AllData` coming from? (Doesn't match with your JSON.)